# uninstall app before start test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

We're trying to write instrumentationTest for our app.

For example I want to write test for authorization/registration.

However before every test I want to be unauthorized? so I need to clean all data, delete db, etc.

So is there any way to delete app or app's data before every test?

Comment: So what is the code one would use? Can you share yours an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Annotations eg:

```
@BeforeEach
```

and put your clean up code there.

Comment: Topic starter (and I too!) is interesting how to remove an apk after or before the test. How would you do this under this annotation? We have ```$adb uninstall <package name>```, but I do not see a way how to do it from ```androidTest```. It can be done as part of gradle tasks which first prepare the environment and later execute test suite, but I am looking for a simpler option.

Comment: As pointed out by Jasmeet, ```Android Test Orchestrator``` might be a right option to do this https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner#architecture

Answer (score 13):

Using Android studio, you can create a test configuration that first uninstalls your app before running a test.

### Create a new External Tool.

1. Go to Preferences -> External Tools.
2. Click on the "+" icon to create a new tool.
3. Set Name to "Uninstall myApp" (or whatever you like)
4. Set Group to "Custom Tools" (or whatever you like)
5. Set Program to "adb"
6. Set Parameters to:

   ```
   uninstall name.of.your.package
   ```
7. Click OK.

You can test that this new tool works by clicking `Tools` -> `External Tools`  -> "Uninstall myApp" (Or for older Android Studio versions, Tools->Custom Tools->"Uninstall myApp").

### Step 2. Create or edit your test configuration.

1. Go to Edit Configurations.
2. Choose the Android Tests configuration that you'd like to modify.
3. Under "Before launch: ...", click the "+" icon.
4. Choose "Run External Tool".
5. In the popup, choose your new tool "Uninstall myApp".
6. Use the arrows so that the External Tool is above any other commands like Gradle-aware Make".
7. Click Ok.

Now, when you run this configuration, your app should be uninstalled first, before your tests are run.

### Sharing

Newer Android Studio version's have "Store as project file" option (in their "Edit Configurations..." dialog).

But that only saves tool's build-step (second step of above), and to to share "External Tools" itself through repository, see:
[Share or Export External tools without using jar-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63891303/8740349)

Comment: I wanted clean all data on each test, not test suite run

Comment: also we need to consider that if this test is uploaded to any suite (lets say AWS) or a CI pipeline it will not work since this is locally done

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked in '13. We have come a long way since then. 
Android has jUnit test runner that comes with a cleanup mechanism under test orchestrator.

Check it out here https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner

Comment: how do I turn it off? I need to KEEP my app between test runs.