# Espresso Instrumentation Tests - how to uninstall or delete the app after the test

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I setup Espresso instrumentation framework to run my Android Functional Automation tests. 
For every test, I want to login to the app and delete the app after I finish the test.

So, I setup something like below:

public class FirstSampleTest extends BaseTest {

```
private final BaseTest baseTest;
```

//  private final ElementUtils elementUtils;

```
public FirstSampleTest() throws InterruptedException {
    this.baseTest = new BaseTest();
}

@Before
public void initiate() throws InterruptedException {
    //I have setup login method here to login to the app after it installs
}

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<SplashScreenActivity> splashScreenActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(SplashScreenActivity.class);

@Test
public void testTheHomeScreen() throws InterruptedException {
   //Some tests go here. 
}

@After
public void teardown() throws InterruptedException {
    //I want to uninstall the app or delete it from the emulator once the test is run 
}

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can **add a gradle task** in the Android Studio `Before launch` section in `Run -> Edit Configurations`.

Click `+` -> Add a gradle-aware Make -> `:app:uninstallAll`

note: "app" in `:app:uninstallAll` depends on your **main** module name. So it can be `:my_module:uninstallAll`, or `:company:uninstallAll`

Comment: Be careful if you have an unrelated, debuggable Android device plugged in while you're doing this. It seems that `:app:uninstallAll` uninstalls your app (the app associated with the currently open project) on _all_ available devices.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling the app from the Instrumentation tests is not possible. However, once all the tests are run, the app is uninstalled automatically.

Note: The app is not uninstalled only when a single test is run. Please run the whole build using the command 
    ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

Comment: I think that user5599934 is talking about the test itself being removed and not your actual app. I think your question is how to remove that actual app between tests which is something I want to to do be able to test my new API 24 permission code. Here is one way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705711/uninstall-app-before-start-test

Comment: how do I get the test to STOP uninstalling the app??