# Share or Export External tools without using jar-file

Tags: android, android-studio, external-tools

I created custom **"run configuration"** and used in him **"external tools"**
my problem is that **"external tools"** are located locally and other developers of the project will not receive it, how can I add it to the project?

One solution is to export the studio settings, get a jar file, but then each developer will have to manually import this jar file, I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this would help ya
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206187849-Sharing-external-tool-config-via-version-control

> There are some "hackish" ways you could probably handle this (via symlinks or junctions), if you just need to run a script, I would recommend using Ant (or even Gradle). Either have Ant do the actual work, or write a simple ant script that wraps and launches the external script (via the  or  target for example). The script, the ant build, and its "Before Launch" configuration can then all be committed to version control.